# Time remaining with os_timer_t

Tags: esp8266

The [Ticker](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Ticker) library for the ESP chips is quite useful, which wraps a `os_timer_t` object. I'd like to be able to see the time remaining on the timer, is it possible to do that witha `os_timer_t` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library just calls `os_timer_setfn` and `os_timer_arm` which will call the callback function after some time. To add the feature to see how many remaining time there is, you would need to extend the library (the `Ticker` class, specifically) to save a timestamp when the timer was started. You can then write a function which returns for how much time is remaining or has passed by doing `uint32_t remaining = timestamp_now() - timestamp_started`.

A good function to hook would be the `_attach_ms` in Ticker.cpp. Add a `uint32_t timestamp_started` variable in the `Timer.h` header for the class. Then set `timestamp_started = system_get_time()` (from `user_interface.h`). Then write a function `uint32_t remainingUs() { return system_get_time() - timestamp_started; }`. Beware of integer overflows -- `system_get_time` returns passed microseconds since µC startup.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an `os_timer` call to see this, but this will work well enough.

Comment: The documentation (http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf, section 3.1) lists no such call for `os_timer` objects.